# svn: E175005: Path already exists

Tags: svn, ubuntu, intellij-idea, apache2

i managed to install an svn service on my ubuntu server following [this tutorial](http://www.oliverdavies.co.uk/blog/2011/10/install-and-configure-subversion-svn-server-ubuntu)
and i am now able to add it as a repository location in intellij IDEA.but now i am getting this odd problem that when i try to create any folder (with any name) inside the repository (from within the intellij idea ) i get the error that says "Path already exists". 
i noticed that when i create a folder directly from the server the new folder will not be shown in intellij subversion repository when i browse it. i use following command to create a folder form within the server :

```
sudo mkdir /home/svn/myProjectRepo 
sudo svnadmin create /home/svn/myProjectRepo
```

-EDIT-

It was a version conflict between svn 1.7 and 1.8.

Comment: Are you trying to add things in `/home/svn/myProjectRepo`? Cause it's a repository, not a working copy: you are not supposed to change its content.

Comment: yeah! i am trying to create a trunk dolder inside home/svn/myProjectRepo . i managed to import files into it but no luck in creating a folder

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing SVN repositories and SVN [working copies](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.tour.initial.html).

Once you have created the repository using `svnadmin create`, you must create a working copy using `svn checkout <repositoryUrl>`, then you can add files and folders inside this working copy. Your files/folders will be stored in the repository once you `svn add` and `svn commit` them.

See the [basic workflow of SVN](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch03s05.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks for answer. as i know working copies are local copies of a repository . the problem is i can not commit changes (like creating a folder) to main repository . i guess there may be a problem with linux permission's.

Comment: now i can see more clearly. files are not actually stored in repository (at least not in folder structure) but my problem stands still , i can not create trunk, branches, tags folder on repository